# how to find out price/extra$1000 deposited

Tags: java, logic, business-logic

The formula that I want to convert in java is

**Over limit Cash Deposit Fee = [(Input $ cash deposit) – ($ Cash deposits included in plan)] / 1000 * (price/each extra $1000 deposited)**

The code that I am writing is

```
int inputCash = 50;
int cashDepsitFromPlan = 40;
int cashDepositOverLimitFee = 2.5;

cashDepositOverLimit = (double) ((inputCash -cashDepsitFromPlan) / 1000) * ???;
```

how do I find ???(price/each extra $1000 deposited)

Comment: That ratio sounds like it should be established by the business rules. It should be represented in your code by a class variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with floating point numbers, you may want to reconsider the use of the `int` data type.

This, for a start, is going to cause all sorts of grief:

```
int cashDepositOverLimitFee = 2.5;
```

You're better off using `double` for everything.

In terms of finding the unknown variable here, that's something specific to your business rules, which aren't shown here.

I'd hazard a guess that the `price/$1000` figure is intimately related to your `cashDepositOverLimitFee` variable such as it being $2.50 for every extra $1000.

That would make the equation:

```
                       inputCash - cashDepsitFromPlan
cashDepositOverLimit = ------------------------------ * cashDepositOverLimitFee
                                   1000
```

which makes sense. The first term on the right hand side is the number of excess $1000 lots you've deposited over and above the plan. You would multiply that by a fee rate (like $2.50 or 2.5%) to get the actual fee.

However, as stated, we can't tell whether it's $2.50 or 2.5% based on what we've seen. You'll have to go back to the business to be certain.

Answer (score 1):

You have to algebraically manipulate the equation to solve for that.

```
cashDepositOverLimitFee = (double) ((inputCash -cashDepsitFromPlan) / 1000) * ???
cashDepositOverLimitFee*1000 = (double) (inputCash -cashDepsitFromPlan) * ???
(cashDepositOverLimitFee*1000) / (double) (inputCash -cashDepsitFromPlan) = ???
??? = (cashDepositOverLimitFee*1000) / (double) (inputCash -cashDepsitFromPlan)
```

Note that the `(double)` cast must remain in order to ensure a floating point result.

Comment: You only need to worry about the bottom line. That's the result. I was just showing the algebra used to get from your equation to the solution.